# PHP/CodeIgniter 2 - call object's __get() method only for a particular object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm working on old CodeIgniter 2 code that I can only change by adding a layer on top, so I'm limited.

Often in the code, a property `$this->secondary_db` is often called even before it was initialized, like such:

```
$this->secondary_db->get_all();
```

Which obviously end up with a Fatal error since `secondary_db` is null.

So, what I tried to do was implement the magic `__get($name)` method but ONLY for `secondary_db` so it would only use the magic method when `$this->secondary_db` is not defined by specifying in the magic method:

```
if ($name == 'secondary_db') { ... load db in a specific way ... }
```

However it creates other fatal errors from other bits of code somewhere that rely on __get() not being called, like such:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property Some_Controller::$benchmark has no effect
>
> Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in system/core/Controller.php

Is there another way to do this or achieve the same thing that I might have forgotten about? Could traits be used for that?

NOTE: I cannot initialize `secondary_db` in the constructor since it's not always the same value.

Comment: the Lava flow coding antipattern? http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm

Comment: Why can't you fix the old code? check the changelist for codeigniter

Comment: Yes haha, precisely stuck in a lava flow, I cannot change all the code as I can merge the current developers' changes into mine, but they are not merging my changes and bug fixes into their code, which explains that I can add stuff but not really change it as it will end up in a merge nightmare every time they make a change

Comment: urgh, that old scenario. massive ticket that takes ages, meanwhile the codebase completely changes while you fix all their broken stuff. i feel for you bro!

Comment: Precisly! Already complicated to merge their changes when they commit tabulation and empty spaces :P